# Upgrade from Rails 3.2, sunspot_rails and sunspot_solr 1.3.3, to Rails 4.x and gems version 2.1.x

Tags: solr, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot

I'm trying to upgrade my Rails app to rails v 4.x and therefore using gems v > 2.x .
I tried to use gems version 1.3.3, but it looks like they are not compatible with new rails version...

I now start solr in development and test doing: sunspot-solr start , leaving default options.

Anyway, I have most of the things working, apart from a strange behavior.

I have a model defined pretty much like this:

class AAA < ActiveRecord::Base

searchable do

```
text    :code

text    :name
```

end

end

Let's say I have a database entry with those values:

```
code: 'ABC'
name 'testy searchy'
```

If I try to do:

```
AAA.search do
   fulltext('abc')
end
```

I get proper result

If I try to do:

```
AAA.search do
   fulltext('ab')
end
```

I get proper result

If I try to do:

```
AAA.search do
   fulltext('testy')
end
```

I get proper result.

But if I try:

```
AAA.search do
   fulltext('tes')
end
```

I don't get any results, whereas in version 1.3.3 everything used to work fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: I tried a brand new / clean rails 4 app with just one active record model with 1 string field, I have the exact same issue described above

Comment: I ended up patching version 1.3.3-stable to work with Rails 4 (only). Here my branch on github https://github.com/clod81/sunspot/tree/1-3-rails4